# dplyr::recode() over selected variables

Tags: r, regex, select, dplyr, recode

I have a data set with columns associated to the same medicine over several months, in it's colnames just change the month number, eg. med1_m1,med1_m2, and so on.
I need to create an indicator variable for this medicine, for all the moths, so I have selected this columns using a regular expression. Over this selected columns, I want to use `recode()` function to create the indicators.
What I have is something like this:

`df <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2),ncol=2))`

`colnames(df) <- c("med1_m1", "med1_m2")`

`df %>% select(matches("^med1_m\\d{1,}"))`

then, I would like to add something like this:

`df %>% select(matches("^med1_m\\d{1,}")) %>% recode("1" = 1, "2" = 0, .default = NULL)`

but I got the following error:

Error in UseMethod("recode") : no applicable method for 'recode' applied to an object of class "data.frame"

Would anyone know how can I recode those selected variables? I need to select them using regex since I have plenty of moths for each medication.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a dataframe to the recode function which is causing the error. I think you can use `mutate()` with `across()`:

`df %>% mutate(across(matches("^med1_m\d{1,}"), ~recode(.x, "1" = 1, "2" = 0, .default = NULL)))`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It works for the toy example but in the real data I get another error: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x no applicable method for 'recode' applied to an object of class "logical"
i Input `..1` is `across(...)`.

Comment: Looks like your regex is picking up a logical column. Confirm that you're matching only the columns you are interested in and/or coerce the logical to character.